# Getting statuses of any user on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm on a project under which we are going to analyse a particular fan page of any product to determine the popularity of that product and which type of people generally prefer those product, for this we are require to get statuses of users who liked that particular fan page. I'm searching for an API but still not able to get the user statuses they have posted on their wall, but when I directly interact on a browser I'm able to see all the posts of any user who have made it public. What is to be done ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get any status post of a User without authorizing that specific User with the `read_stream` permission, not even public ones.

Keep in mind that you will most likely not get read_stream approved in the [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) process:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

**TL;DR:** you can´t do it.

Comment: I'm new to this, can you please tell me how to get this read_stream permission.

Comment: it´s all in the facebook docs (authorization, permissions, review, ...). i´ve added some more information in my answer.